# How to select the non numeric characters from a string in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an issue for which I cannot seem to locate a reasonable solution for.

I have a php string variable `$PaidUpCapital="฿ 10,000000";` meaning `$PaidUpCapital` is equal to 10 million thai bhat. How can I strip all the numeric and comma characters and get the currency symbol from this variable using php?

Comment: Is the currency symbol always in the same place? If so, you can do this `echo $PaidUpCapital[0]`.

Comment: This is not an array rather a string variable. Therefore it does not have any index. And yes it is always there. I just need to see how can I remove all numeric and comma characters to get just the currency symbol.

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribizew 
I cannot be sure how many characters is it, So I need a bit more dynamic method than this one. It can be two characters based currency symbol instead aswell.

Comment: Then explode with a space and get the first item ([demo](http://ideone.com/TWpbsm)).

Comment: @RabiaRanaKhan Try it first before you say it cannot be done ;) Remember that you need UTF-8 enabled in the `<head>` section but I suspect you already have that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression and the [function preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
preg_replace("/[0-9, ]/", "", $PaidUpCapital);
```

Check it [here](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ir4)

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex to remove the unwanted characters but you might want to approach this another way because regex is quite slow compared to other methods.

If `$PaidUpCapital` always has the same format: `<symbol><space><amount>`
You can do the following instead:

```
echo explode(' ', $PaidUpCapital)[0];
echo substr($PaidUpCapital, 0, strpos($PaidUpCapital, ' '));
```

Both methods do the same thing, grab all characters before the space as  `strlen("฿")` has a length of 3 and `strlen("$€")` has a length of 2 so to make it compatible with every symbol you'd have to use a delimiter.

Comment: [_Premature optimization is the root of all evil_](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization) -> don't assume too early that speed is an issue ;-)

Comment: @joanolo: now I better understand why you replace the characters one by one with your pattern.